# How to add GeoTIFF tags into EXIF image data in Python?

Tags: python, exif, qgis, geotiff

I wrote a script that gets an image as input and then convert it to tiff format. Now I need to add some GeoTIFF tags into the EXIF image data (e.g. pixel size, coordinates, etc) so I could work with this image in QGIS.

If Python doens't have any lib that can handle this I could migrate this script to C++. Anny suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need use gdal library.

```
import gdal

gdal.AllRegister()

inputImagePath = "your geotiff"
inputdataset = gdal.Open(inputImagePath)

inputdataset.SetMetadataItem("TEST","TEST METADATA")

inputdataset = None
```

this code add a metadata item "TEST" in the image.